# Como enviar un token en un header Api fetch

Tags: api, fetch

estoy incursionando en fetch para hacer peticiones a una API publica que me permita ver las cotizaciones del dolar de mi pais, el proveedor de la API me da una clave que debo incluirla en la header del request de la siguiente forma Autorizathion = BEARER+{token}, la verdad no se como hacerla, intente esto pero el firefox da error de : "Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://api.xxxxxxxx.com/usd_of (razón: la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no coincide con 'http://xxxxxxxxxx.com'), paso el codigo que estuve tratando de hacer andar, gracias por la ayuda...

```
const myHeader = new Headers({
'Authorization': 'BEARER xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
});

const myInit = { 
           method: 'GET',
           headers: myHeader,
           mode: 'cors',
           cache: 'default' };


   const myRequest = new Request('http://api.xxxxxxx.com/usd_of',myInit);

   fetch(myRequest)
      .then (response => response.json())
      .then (data => {
      console.log(data)
   })
```

Comment: ¿Ya probaste ejecutando la solicitud desde Postman, solo para eliminar factores?

Comment: Desde postman me tira los datos sin problemas, como soy nuevo en esto supuse que se podrian consumir desde un nagevador, pero parece que no es asi,

Comment: Tengo la teoría de que te falta el Header de Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si el api es rest y estas en un navegador como puedo observar en el mensaje de error es por que el api no debe ser consumida en el navegador por seguridad los navegadores bloquean el. Consumo de otras apis que estén en otro dominio es por. Eso tu mensaje.

Como se debería hacer en este caso hay dos caminos uno es que sea un api pública y se use  json p para poder consumir a otro dominio o usar también permisos en estos apis que dejen al navegador saltarse estas restricciones

Este caso si es como dices el api la maneja un servidor externo que no va a cambiar sus headers de respuesta  entonce este paso no es factible.

Lo más. Factible es que consumas este servicio desde servidor es decir consumas desde tu servidor y no en el cliente o navegador ahí si te permitirá hacer ya que no tiene ningún bloqueo de navegador y mediante un api tuya la muestres en tu web.

Además protegerlas el token del servicio del dolar. Esta opción es la más factible y la correcta.

Comment: Gracias no se si entiendo bien pues recien estoy empezando pero lo que quiereo es lo que pide esta pagina para hacerla arrancar, lo lazo desde mi vsc usando live server  ---  http://estadisticasbcra.com/api/documentacion

Comment: En resumen tienes que consumir en tu server no en el. Navegador

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes cambiar el `mode` a `no-cors` y te funcionara seguramente.

```
mode: 'no-cors',
```

Comment: Esta respuesta ha llegado a revisión por ser considerada de baja calidad. Léete [answer] para aprender a realizar buenas respuestas. Ofrece información de apoyo para que la comunidad entienda porque esta respuesta soluciona el problema, gracias.